# PHP: what is more efficient? - in_array checking or a single MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, loops, joomla

I have users in Joomla! 2.5x. They have different settings for getting emails from admin (On/Off). And I have to check those settings while emails are sending to them.
Unfortunately now there is a rather strange architecture (I'm not the author) when the settings for EVERY user are checking in the loop. As a result as many users we have, so we have to perform the checking.
I suppose two ways to solve the problem.

1. Before sending the email to a single user we ask our DB which of state for getting emails he has.

   LOOP

   ```
   if(checkUserSettings()) // performs a single query to DB

      sendMail(...)
   ```
2. We get all users from DB which have the email settings in the *On* state. We store them in the array and perform the in_array checking before loop.

   LOOP

   ```
   if(in_array($syst_user->id, $users_ids)) // contains array of users id id

       sendMail(...)
   ```

sendMail() in essense is a PHPmailer.

So which of those approaches is more efficient in practice?

Comment: I would imagine in_array would be faster because it's not sending a packet to MySQL, but this can only be proved with actual benchmarks.

Comment: Way 3: Use the MySQL Query to get all users with the setting enabled, send the emails to them in the loop. One query, no further checking nessecary.

Comment: @DaveChen u r right, but if the array reaches >100*n items, a single query like Gerald Schneider said would be faster (and, in my opinion, easier to handle)